# Approximate versions of Segre's Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Consider projective $2$-space over a finite field of odd prime characteristic $p$. We say a set of points, $A$, in this space is an arc if any line meets it in at most two points. We say that an arc is complete if it is not contained in a larger arc. It isn't hard to see an arc has size at most $p+1$.

A well-known result of Segre states the following:

> An arc of size $p+1$ is a conic

Here a [conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) is basically an algebraic set defined by an equation of degree at most two.
It seems that having a robust structure theorem for arcs that are almost of maximal size might be helpful in studying certain questions in this setting. To my surprise, I recently learned that there might be some hope of this. Namely in 1990 Voloch proved the following [remarkable relaxation](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/arcs_prime.pdf) of Segre's result

> An arc of size $\frac{44}{45} p +O(1)$ is contained within a conic.

My question is how much more robust can one get in terms of approximate versions. Here are some specific questions:

> What is the best known lower bound on the constant in Voloch's theorem. In other words, what is the largest known family of complete arcs that are not contained within a conic (in fields of prime order)?

It would be great if one could get a power savings in $p$, but that seems unlikely. Indeed it seems likely that after removing enough points from a conic one can add a single point off the conic which prevents it from being a subset.

Alternatively, I'd like to say something like that if an arc has size near $p$ then a large portion of it can be contained in a conic (or it can be contained in the finite union of a controlled number of concics). Let me venture a guess at a possible structure theorem

> Is the following true: If $A$ is an arc and $|A| > p^{1-\delta}$ for some small $\delta$, then there exists a small constant $c(\delta)$, such that there always exists a conic $C$ such that $|C \cap A | \geq c(\delta) |A|$.

I'd be interesting in anything known on these problems and examples that show obstructions to these sorts of conclusions.

**Note added**: After posting the question I found [another paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669887800525) by Voloch which constructs complete arcs of size $p/2$, giving a lower bound on my first question. The key idea is to look at subsets of elliptic curves. This argument seems to rely on the group law of the elliptic curve, so it isn't clear to me if there are potential obstructions from higher degree curves. In other words, it might be that one needs to include elliptic curves in addition to conics in a possible structure theorem.

Comment: The last sentence is very similar to the conclusion reached by Ben Green in his paper "Approximate Algebraic Structure" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0093), section 4.4. He conjectures that arcs in projective 2-space of size $\geq cp$ have all but $o(p)$ points on a curve of degree at most 3! This paper is concerned with a lot of examples in the vein of what you ask in this question, so it might be of interest.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: thanks for the relevant comment. I was unaware  of this paper and it is very much on point.